# вывести список подстраниц с второй вложенности

Tags: wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста с выводом подстраниц списком

**главная**

- **страница**(здесь начинаем вывод всех подстраниц данной страницы, включая пункт Страница)

  - **подстраница**(здесь выводим такой же список страниц, включая пункт Страница)

    - **подподстраница**(здесь выводим такой же список страниц, включая пункт Страница)
- **вторая страница**(здесь начинаем вывод всех подстраниц данной страницы, вторая страница)

  - **подстраница**(здесь выводим такой же список страниц, включая пункт вторая страница)

Можно ли это сделать с помощью функции `wp_list_pages();` или проще создать шаблон страницы и сделать вывод меню с этими страницами?

```
if(get_ancestors( 869, 'page' )){
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=869&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
}elseif(get_ancestors( 870, 'page' )){
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=870&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
}elseif(get_ancestors( 871, 'page' )){
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=871&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
}
if ($children) {
echo '<ul class="page-menu">'.$children.'</ul>';
}
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А что вы сделали сами, что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: Я понимаю, когда спрашивают какую функцию применить, но что мешает почитать документацию к известной функции - нет, не пойму.  Ида. не понятно что в итоге надо-то.

Comment: @KAGG Design
вставил код в пост, я не понимаю как вывести список подстраниц родителя второй вложенности и чтобы он отображался весь на всех подстраницах.

Comment: Для того, чтобы показать вложенную структуру, неплохо подходят списки. Отформатировал текст, тут можно посмотреть на источник: [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может не самый лучший вариант зато работает

```
function is_tree( $id_this_page ){
global $post;
if ( is_page( $id_this_page ) ) return true;
$anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
if( is_page() && $ancestor == $id_this_page ) return true;
}
return false;}
echo '<ul class="menu-page">';
if(is_tree(869)){
echo '<li class="menu-page-parent"><a href="'.get_permalink(869).'">'.get_the_title(869).'</a>';
echo '<ul class="menu-page-child">';
echo wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=869&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
echo '</ul></li>';
}elseif(is_tree(870)){
echo '<li class="menu-page-parent"><a href="'.get_permalink(870).'">'.get_the_title(870).'</a>';
echo '<ul class="menu-page-child">';
echo wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=870&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
echo '</ul></li>';
}elseif(is_tree(871)){
echo '<li class="menu-page-parent"><a href="'.get_permalink(871).'">'.get_the_title(871).'</a>';
echo '<ul class="menu-page-child">';
echo wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=871&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать, что проще для вас. Я бы сделал отдельный шаблон для страницы на основе примерно такой функции (дает список всех детей страницы) :

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

global $post; 

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Шорт-код [wpb_childpages] .
А дальше смотрите, до какой глубины организовать цикл и что выводить.